# Read multiple xlsx files and store filtered data.frame rows to dedicated worksheet

Tags: r, for-loop, openxlsx

Up to now I cannot share any code snippets I tried before w/o succes however here's the basic idea:

I have a couple of excel files stored in a dedicated folder based on a unique naming scheme eg.

```
filABC.xlsx
filDEF.xlsx
filGHI.xlsx
```

Each of them contains a special worksheet, always named with the same name eg. "sh1" no matter of the file itself.

In addition I have a dataframe stored in R named "df" including consolidated data with parts of the naming scheme in variable V01:

```
| V01 | V02 | V03 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 1.2 | 1.3 |
| ABC | 3.2 | 2.3 |
| DEF | 5.5 | 2.3 |
| DEF | 4.1 | 3.9 |
| DEF | 3.5 | 2.0 |
| GHI | 6.3 | 8.4 |
```

Now I need to update the sheet "sh1" in each xlsx-file with the corresponding subset of dataframe "df" based on all rows with the unique entries from V01

Referring to the example files mentioned above:
The basic idea is

1. open the first xlsx-file from the folder "filABC.xlsx"
2. define an index based on the name part "ABC"
3. prepare/filter the matching rows from dataframe "df" based on the previous index "ABC"
4. overwrite all data of sheet "sh1"
5. save the file "filABC.xlsx"
6. move on to the next excel file "filDEF.xlsx"...
   [...]

To be honest I am not really new to R but currently I have no clue on how to solve this issue based on loops, lapply or whatever might be smart and necessary to be considered...

Any hints and even smart solutions very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom function, `split` and `mapply` you could do:

```
library(openxlsx)

write_to_xl <- function(x, y) {
  fn <- paste0("fil", y, ".xlsx")
  wb <- loadWorkbook(fn)
  writeData(wb, "sh1", x)
  saveWorkbook(wb, fn, overwrite = TRUE)
}
df_split <- split(df, df$V01)

mapply(write_to_xl, df_split, names(df_split))
```

**DATA**

```
df <- data.frame(
  V01 = c("ABC", "ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "DEF", "GHI"),
  V02 = c("1.2", "3.2", "5.5", "4.1", "3.5", "6.3"),
  V03 = c("1.3", "2.3", "2.3", "3.9", "2.0", "8.4")
)
```

Comment: your solution is very smart and works out of the box - thank you stefan!!!